# Problemas de alineación en la lista de preguntas

Tags: bug, diseño

Como se ve en la imagen abajo, hay algunos problemas de alineación en la página de preguntas. Las palabras "respuesta" y "respuestas" genera que se expanda el cuadro.

Esto desalinea el resto de los elementos en la fila. Si se fijan bien, la cantidad de vistas, el titulo de la pregunta, y las etiquetas también arrastran el corrimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoy día ese problema no existe, como muestra el recuadro de color rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, ignoro si la corrección de bugs aparece reportada en alguna parte de SO.

Comment: Sobre lo de _ignoro si la corrección de bugs aparece reportada en alguna parte de SO_: normalmente se reportan en el Meta de [so] o Meta de [se] y cuando un empleado de la empresa lo corrige le añade la etiqueta [meta-tag:estado-completado].